# how can I make JavaFX webView accepts required HTML5 tag?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, javafx-webengine

Required html5 is not working in JavaFX web browser I test the browser here http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp and in https://html5test.com/ confirm that my browser support fields validation :( I don't know what is going wrong.

```
JFXPanel jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();
frame2 = new JFrame("");
frame2.add(jfxPanel);
Platform.runLater(() -> {
WebView webView = new WebView();

webView.getEngine().load(url);});
```

Comment: Are you saying that the `required` attribute isn't working on form fields? Such as: `<input type="textbox" required>`?

Comment: yes I'm using a input with the tag required in a form and it doesn't work